# store facts in database and yaml file both in puppet

Tags: puppet

In puppet master is there any way to store facts of each client in database and yaml file. Currently it is working with yaml file but i want to store it in both the places. How can i do it. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

storeconfigs should work along side, check out:

http://projects.puppetlabs.com/projects/1/wiki/using_stored_configuration